# Ajax code suddenly stopped working?

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, css-selectors, jquery-selectors

I'm losing my mind right now, I don't know what happened. I wrote a code where users could write a comment, and as soon as you submit it the comment shows up. Everything worked perfectly fine until, playing with the program, I noticed that when I wrote a very large comment, the comment bubble wasn't 'expanding', adapting its size, and an error appeared here (specifically in the if condition):

```
    $query = "select user,comment,date from comments where user='$name' and comment='$comment'";
    $select = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    if($row=mysqli_fetch_array($select))
    {
        $name=$row['user'];
        $comment=$row['comment'];
        $time=$row['date'];
```

I don't remember the error itself, I ignored it at first because I wanted to fix the bubble mess, so I proceeded with the CSS. When I finished, I noticed that everything was working as it should, except the ajax part. The comment no longer appears when submited (I have to refresh the page), and the error doesn't appear anymore, so I'm really, really desperate. I compared the current code with an older one that worked and it's exactly the same, except for some CSS classes, I'm so confused.

I'm only posting that part of the code because it's the one that made the error appear when the comment was too large, but please tell me if more is needed.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: Try and get out of the habit of declaring SQL statements in throw-away variables that are used only once. It's a lot easier to follow code where the query is supplied directly to the function, and there's no longer a chance of messing up and sending in `$sql3` instead of the visually similar `$sql8`.

Comment: That's why working with a copy helps. There's also no ajax here.

Comment: chris85, please write that separately so I can credit you. When I was adding more code to the post I noticed I was missing an id in one div that, as you said, triggered the ajax events. I don't know how I missed that... thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Per your statement:

> I compared the current code with an older one that worked and it's exactly the same, except for some CSS classes, I'm so confused.

A removed/altered CSS class would cause an AJAX event to not fire, if it were called by that name.

e.g.

```
$('.test').click(function(){
```

wouldn't occur if

```
<a class="test"...>
```

were (was per comment, [Ajax code suddenly stopped working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47516798/ajax-code-suddenly-stopped-working/47518339#comment81990411_47516798)) changed to:

```
<a class="not_a_test">
```